# Why isn't the empty set an element of $A \times B$, while it is a relation from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A$ be $\{1,2\}$, let $B$ be $\{x,y\}$.

According to the information I get from most textbooks, 
$$A \times B = \{(a,b): a\in A\text{ and } b\in B\}$$

$$A \times B = \{(1,x),(1,y),(2,x),(2,y)\}$$

But the smallest relation from $A$ to $B$ is the empty set. Presumably this is because *'the empty set is a subset of any set'* is vacuously true.

But I don't understand how is the empty set not a member of $A \times B$, while it is a subset of $A \times B$. Two reasons why I am confused.

1. The empty set can be an ordered pair, because *'All elements of the empty set is an ordered pair'* is vacuously true.

So surely *'All elements of the empty set is a member of $A$ and $B$'* is vacuously true as well, thus making it an element of $A \times B$?

2. If the empty set is a subset of $A \times B$, then, surely, it must be true that 'all element of the empty set is a member of $A$ and $B$' is true, be it vacuously so or not. If so, shouldn't the empty set be a member of $A \times B$?

Or am I confused by the idea between membership and subset?

Comment: Elements (or members) != subsets.  Relations from $A$ to $B$ are subsets of $A\times B$, not elements of $A\times B$.  On the other hand, ordered $(A,B)$ pairs are elements of $A\times B$, not subsets of $A\times B$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confused. Your statement 1 is incorrect; a correct version would say

> The empty set can be ***a set of ordered pairs***, because *'Every element of the empty set is an ordered pair'* is vacuously true.

I mean, if I say *"$S$ is a set all of whose elements are purple"*, then it follows that $S$ is a set of purple elements (perhaps vacuously, if $S$ is empty), but it does not follow that $S$ is purple.

The empty set is not *itself* an ordered pair.

As for statement 2, here is a general fact: if $C\subseteq A$, and $D\subseteq B$, then $C\times D\subseteq A\times B$. Now, you've correctly stated that $\varnothing\subseteq A$, and $\varnothing\subseteq B$, for all sets $A$ and $B$, which you phrased as *'every element of the empty set is a member of $A$ and $B$'*, but **this implies that** $\varnothing\times\varnothing\subseteq A\times B$. This doesn't tell us anything new, since $\varnothing\times\varnothing=\varnothing$, and we know that $\varnothing\subseteq S$ for every set $S$.

Even if it **were** the case that $\varnothing\in A$ and $\varnothing\in B$, that would tell you that $(\varnothing,\varnothing)\in A\times B$, but the ordered pair whose entries are both $\varnothing$ is not at all the same as $\varnothing$ itself.

---

Let's tackle this another way. You'd like to know whether $\varnothing\in A\times B$, where $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{x,y\}$. Then the question you need to ask is:
$$\text{Is there some $\alpha\in A$ and $\beta\in B$ such that $\varnothing=(\alpha,\beta)$?}$$
The answer is clearly no, there is no such $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: If you're a computer programmer (in a statically-typed language with templates/generics), it may help to think of the × operation as the function `Set< Pair<T, U> > CartesianProduct(Set<T> a, Set<U> b)`.  The return value can *be* an empty set, but it can't *contain* an empty set because then the type would have to be `Set<Set>` instead of `Set<Pair>`.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: Thank you so much! That is a very detailed explanation. It sorted out a lot of my confusions.
But I have a further question, we know the following 2 propositions are true:

1. A×B is the set of all ordered pairs whose first term is in A and second term in B.

2. Every element of the empty set is a member of A and B.

If so, shouldn't there be at least an ordered pair belonging to A×B, whose first term is a member of both the empty set and A, and likewise for the second term? And if this is correct, is that the ordered pair (∅,∅)?

Comment: @DanielMak: Note that I gave the general form of that proposition 2 in my answer: if every element of $C$ is an element of $A$, and every element of $D$ is an element of $B$ (equivalently: if $C\subseteq A$ and $D\subseteq B$), then for every $c\in C$ and every $d\in D$, the ordered pair $(c,d)$ is an element of $A\times D$ (equivalently: $C\times D\subseteq A\times B$). Hopefully you agree so far, and you understand that you are just looking at the case $C=D=\varnothing$.

Comment: The point is that (by definition) ***nothing*** is an element of the empty set. Look at what you yourself said: `whose first term is a member of both the empty set and A`. There is no such thing, because nothing is a member of the empty set, much less a member of **both** the empty set and $A$.

Comment: It is **vacuously true** that *"for every element $\alpha\in\varnothing\cap A$, and element $\beta\in\varnothing\cap B$, the ordered pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ is an element of $A\times B$"* because $\varnothing\cap S=\varnothing$ for any set $S$, and $\varnothing$ has no elements at all.

Comment: Allow me to clarify this to make sure that I understand: by definition ∅ has no element, this is why (c,d) of A×B does not exist if C=D=∅ (because nothing is both a member of ∅ and A or B). 

The vacuously true statement 'Every element of ∅ is a member of A and B.' cannot make (c,d) of A×B exists, because this statement is only true ASSUMING IF the empty set has elements in it - which it does not. Since ∅ does not have any element, the requirement that the terms of (c,d) to be in ∅ and A or B fails. Am I right?

And may I say thank you so much again for your patient explanation!

Comment: @DanielMak: Absolutely right. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are confused between membership and subset.  You have listed $A \times B$ in your third line.  As $|A|=|B|=2$, it has $4$ elements.  Are any of them $\emptyset$?  No, so $\emptyset \not \in A \times B$.  It is true that $\emptyset \subset A \times B$.  Under $1$, it is not true that the empty set is an ordered pair.  The line starting "So surely" demonstrates that the empty set is a subset of $A \times B$, not an element of $A \times B$. As a relation between is a *subset* of $A \times B$, and the empty set is a subset of $A \times B$ it is a relation.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you made between 1 and 2. Shows that the empty set is a subset of $A\times B$ not an element of it.